# Download Gridview specific Column data to word file

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I have a GridView on a page. The user is able to input data in that GridView then I am downloading an Word file on Submit Event.

Now the question is: **How can I download specific Column data to that word file?** That word file also contains other data from different fields from same the page, which are working fine.

Below is the code for GridView: (Grid is binding on page load)

```
private void SetPreviousData()
{
    int rowIndex = 0;
    if (ViewState["CurrentTable"] != null)
    {
        DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                TextBox box1 = (TextBox)GridViewData11.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("Data1");
                TextBox box2 = (TextBox)GridViewData11.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("Data2");
                TextBox box3 = (TextBox)GridViewData11.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[3].FindControl("Data3");
                TextBox box4 = (TextBox)GridViewData11.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[4].FindControl("Data4");

                box1.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Column1"].ToString();
                box2.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Column2"].ToString();
                box3.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Column3"].ToString();
                box4.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Column4"].ToString();

                rowIndex++;
            }
        }
```

Below code is for Download data to Word file:

```
public void GenerateWordDoc()
{     
    string strBody = "<html>" +
        "<body>" +
            "<div> <b> Details </b></div> <br>" +

               "<table MAX width=\"701\" height=\"646\" border=\"1\">   <tr><td width=\"191\" height=\"26\" >Name  of user </td> <td height=\"86\" > Comments</td><td colspan=\"3\">&nbsp;</td></tr>  </table>" +
        "</body>" +
        "</html>";

    string fileName = “wordfile.doc”;

    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Type", "application/msword");
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
    Response.Write(strBody);
}
```

Comment: What is different about this data and the "other data from different fields"?

Comment: @Crowcoder this data is input from user and other is from database.

Comment: it is still just data. The only problem I see is that you are overwriting `boxX.Text` every loop iteration. You need to inject that data into your document on each loop or store it in a list and work with it after - or better yet, forget about the gridview and just pull it out of the `DataTable` directly.